# importing pyautogui on python 3.9.6 not working

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

I tried to import pyautogui on python 3.9.6 and I got these error messages. I tried installing pyobjc and more but its still not working. Any ways to fix this? Also this is my error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyautogui/_pyautogui_osx.py", line 5, in <module>
    import Quartz
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Quartz/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import AppKit
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/AppKit/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import Foundation
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Foundation/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import CoreFoundation
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/CoreFoundation/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import objc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/objc/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from ._context import *  # noqa: F401, F403, E402
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/objc/_context.py", line 29, in <module>
    from typing import Any
  File "/Users/ognen/Desktop/Programs/typing.py", line 8, in <module>
    pyautogui.write(x, interval = 0.01)   
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pyautogui' has no attribute 'write' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ognen/Desktop/Programs/BestPhone.py", line 19, in <module>
    import pyautogui
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 146, in <module>
    from . import _pyautogui_osx as platformModule
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyautogui/_pyautogui_osx.py", line 7, in <module>
    assert False, "You must first install pyobjc-core and pyobjc: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html"
AssertionError: You must first install pyobjc-core and pyobjc: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html
Skynet-prototype-256:Programs ognen$ python3 BestPhone.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyautogui/_pyautogui_osx.py", line 5, in <module>
    import Quartz
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Quartz/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import AppKit
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/AppKit/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import Foundation
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Foundation/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import CoreFoundation
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/CoreFoundation/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import objc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/objc/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from ._context import *  # noqa: F401, F403, E402
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/objc/_context.py", line 29, in <module>
    from typing import Any
  File "/Users/ognen/Desktop/Programs/typing.py", line 8, in <module>
    pyautogui.write(x, interval = 0.01)   
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pyautogui' has no attribute 'write' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ognen/Desktop/Programs/BestPhone.py", line 19, in <module>
    import pyautogui
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 146, in <module>
    from . import _pyautogui_osx as platformModule
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyautogui/_pyautogui_osx.py", line 7, in <module>
    assert False, "You must first install pyobjc-core and pyobjc: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html"
AssertionError: You must first install pyobjc-core and pyobjc: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html
```